# Google authentication freeRadius server stop working

Tags: ubuntu, freeradius

It is very funny issue. THe Free radius server has been up and running for almost one year, no any issue. All the sudden it stops working this week.

I test the domain user from local:

radtest jzwang@yyy.yyy.yy 'yyy11111' localhost 18120 testing123
Sending Access-Request of id 149 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
User-Name = "jzwang@yyy.yyy.yy"
User-Password = "yyy11111"
NAS-IP-Address = 10.10.10.10
NAS-Port = 18120

Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Sending Access-Request of id 149 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
User-Name = "jzwang@yyy.yyy.yy"
User-Password = "yyy11111"
NAS-IP-Address = 10.10.10.10
NAS-Port = 18120

Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Sending Access-Request of id 149 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
User-Name = "jzwang@yyy.yyy.yy"
User-Password = "yyy11111"
NAS-IP-Address = 10.10.10.10
NAS-Port = 18120
Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000

radclient: no response from server for ID 149 socket 3

But the Radius.log shows  Auth: Login OK. 
debug shows..
+- entering group authenticate {...}
pam_pass: using pamauth string  for pam.conf lookup
pam_pass: authentication succeeded for 
++[pam] returns ok
Login OK: [jzwang@yyy.yyy.yy/yyy11111] (from client localhost port 18120)

I switch to Pam_unix.so and test local user account, works well. Only Domain user accounts (using Pam_lsass.so) have issues.

Comment: My feeling is it is slow somewhere. it takes longer time to response the requests? What should I do next...Thank you

Comment: output of `rpm -qa freeradius`